# How to add a 'foreach' loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

A client asked me to edit some really old code to add in images to their search functionality, but does not want to pay to recreate the entire script.

On one page the search script is coded in PHP, so I used this script to search through a folder of images, and return all images that matched the searches part number:

```
foreach (glob("./item_images/$partnumber*.jpg") as $filename) {
    echo "<a href='$filename' rel='shadowbox[item]'><img width='75' src='$filename'/></a>";
}
```

On another part of the website, the search is done in Javascript (which I'm not overly familiar with), and I'm stumped on how to turn the above into javascript. It doesn't look like the "glob" function can be used outside of PHP.

Any advice would be appricated.

Comment: You can't search the server filesystem with JS.

Comment: with JS you can, however the runtime in the browser you can't

Comment: "*A client asked me to edit some really old code...but does not want to pay to recreate the entire script.*" - and why do you want to keep this client?

Comment: The browser will have to send an AJAX request to the server, which can do the search in PHP.

Comment: I would either use AJAX and let the PHP return a filtered result, if there is a high update on the images, or there are soo many of them. Or you can inject the Array once into a script-node and filter that in JS. That's up to you. You have to be more specific on your actual problem, to get a good answer.

Comment: Did you try adding an image file in that folder and see if the application works and sees the additional image where it should? I a mean: the title is misleading: you don't need to add a whole for loop; you need to make sure it reads some more images in the existing loop, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily inject PHP data structures in to javascript using `json_encode()`.  For example, this simple code below would create an array using `glob()` and then write it as a javascript literal array.

```
<?php
$collection = glob("./item_images/$partnumber*.jpg");
?>
<script>
// write array from PHP into javascript
var collection = <?php echo json_encode($collection); ?>;
// iterate through the array
for(i=0;i<collection.length;i++) {
    // do something in loop
}
</script>
```

Comment: may I suggest to inject all images (jpegs) in this case: `$collection = glob("./item_images/*.jpg");` not just a subset

Comment: @Thomas I just copied the `glob()` statement directly from the question. So that is something for OP to determine what they are trying to query against.  This is not really even pertinent to my answer anyway, which was intended to show how to inject any array or object structure from PHP into javascript.